# Zeta functions of schemes of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: schemes, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series

Let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$.  In Section 11 of my 2008 paper in J. Number Theory, "Ring structures on groups of arithmetic functions," I define an additive analogue $\Omega_X(s)$ of the (multiplicative) zeta function $$\zeta_X(s) = \prod_{x \in |X|} \frac{1}{1-(\#\kappa(x))^{-s}}$$ of $X$, namely, the formal Dirichlet series
$$\Omega_X(s) = \zeta(s) \sum_q  \# X(\mathbb{F}_q) q^{-s},$$
where $q$ ranges over all prime powers greater than $1$.  Does anyone know what the abscissa of convergence or absolute convergence of $\Omega_X(s)$ is (say, ignoring the factor of $\zeta(s)$, i.e., ignoring the pole of $\zeta(s)$, so just considering the series $\sum_q  \# X(\mathbb{F}_q) q^{-s}$)?  For $\zeta_X(s)$, it is known that its abscissa of absolute convergence is less than or equal to $\dim(X)$.  I'd also be curious if it is known exactly what the abscissa of convergence or absolute convergence of $\zeta_X(s)$ is.  Finally, I'm curious if anyone has either proved or disproved Conjecture 4.2 of my paper:

> $\DeclareMathOperator\Re{Re}$Suppose $F(s)$ and $G(s)$ are Dirichlet series converging absolutely for $\Re(s) > \sigma$ and $\Re(s) > \tau$, respectively.
>
> 1. If $F(s)$ and $G(s)$ are multiplicative, then $F(s) \odot G(s)$ converges absolutely for $\Re(s) > \sigma + \tau - 1$.
> 2. If $F(s)$ and $G(s)$ are additive, then $F(s) \bigcirc\!\!\!\!\!\!* \;\;G(s)$ converges absolutely for $\Re(s) > \max \{1, \sigma + \tau - 1\}$.

Here is the paper: [Ring structures on groups of arithmetic functions](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2007.07.011).

Note that a formal Dirichlet series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n^s}$ is **multiplicative** if the arithmetic function $f$ is multiplicative, and the given Dirichlet series is **additive** if the arithmetic function $f$ is additive.  The formal Dirichlet series $\zeta_X(s)$ is multiplicative, and the formal Dirichlet series $\Omega_X(s)$ is additive.

Note also that, if $X$ and $Y$ are schemes of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$, then
$$\zeta_{X \times Y}(s) = \zeta_X(s) \odot \zeta_Y(s)$$
and
$$\Omega_{X \times Y}(s) = \Omega_X(s) \bigcirc\!\!\!\!\!\!* \;\; \Omega_Y(s)$$
as formal Dirichlet series.

EDIT NOTE: I changed the notation $\alpha_X(s)$ to $\Omega_X(s)$ to match the notation I use at the end of my paper.  I state there that $\Omega_X(s)/\zeta(s)$ converges absolutely for $\operatorname{Re} s > \dim(X)$, which I believe, since getting rid of the $\log p$ factor should only decrease the abscissa of absolute convergence, but perhaps the abscissa is even smaller than $\dim(X)$.

Comment: I edited in the statement of Corollary 4.2, but, since `\ostar` is not defined here, I had to do some serious abuse to simulate it.  I would be grateful to anyone who can replace the resulting abomination.

Comment: Isn't this $\zeta(s)$ times the logarithmic derivative of $\zeta_X (s)$?

Comment: Oh, not quite, you've dropped the $\log p$ factors.

Comment: To make the statement of the conjecture more self-contained, could you indicate in the post, after stating Conjecture 4.2, what is meant by multiplicative and additive Dirichlet series?  This presumably refers to a property of their coefficients.

Comment: @KConrad.  Done.  It just means that the arithmetic functions that they come from are multiplicative and additive, respectively.

Comment: @WillSawin. The reason to drop the $\log p$ factors is that the map from multiplicative to additive formal Dirichlet series is then defined over any ring, not just over $\mathbb{C}$, and is functorial in the base ring. The map I call Log is an injective ring homomorphism from the ring of multiplicative formal Dirichlet series over $\mathbb{Z}$ to the ring of additive multiplicative formal Dirichlet series over $\mathbb{Z}$. With the $\log p$ factors, that wouldn't be possible. It is important that the series $\zeta_X$ and $\Omega_X = \text{Log}(\zeta_X)$ lie in those two rings, respectively.